# Message while debugging wcf method call

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have hosted WCF library on the IIS7 on my local machine. My web application is accessing this service. When I debug the service method, I got the prompt message for attaching the w3wp process. How it is resolved permanently as i am facing this frequently. Below is the screenshot

[image]

Is there any settings required in IIS. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

- Close all Visual Studio instances.
- Ensure that you are a member of the local debuggers group (Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Local Security Policy, Security Settings, Local Poliies, User Rights Assignment, Debug Programs).
- Change the following registry key  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Debugger\DisableAttachSecurityWarning` from `0` to `1`.
- Restart Visual Studio.

(Source: http://blog.geeky.cc/post/2010/07/19/Disable-Attach-Security-Warning.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @mellamokb. It saves time for me now

Comment: I think this is  for all the application running in VS2010. A good trick but may have some security threats, isn't it?

Comment: If you are unsure about the third step, which disables the security warning altogether, here is a more nuanced answer: http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/11/13/attach-debugger-security-warning.aspx.  I think if you just do the second step (make yourself a member of local debuggers or local admins), that should remove the message from popping up,  and you can leave the security warning enabled in the registry.  Try it, and let me know what you find.

Comment: If i skip third step, It is not working. When i follow all three steps it is working fine, but does not showing my pop up window (my app specific pop up page) after completion of debugging.